# How do I make command handler with aliases

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a command handler without aliases and I need to make my command handler to support aliases. This is my current command handler:

```
fs.readdir(__dirname + "/commands", (err, files) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    let jsfiles = files.filter((f) => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
    if(jsfiles.length < 0) {
        Log.log("[WARN] No commands to load.");
        return;
    }

    console.log(`[INFO] Loading ${jsfiles.length} commands.`);

    jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
        let fileName = f.substring(0, f.length - 3);
        let fileContents = require("./commands/" + f);

        // you can uncomment if you want to see which commands have been loaded
        // console.log(`Command ${f} loaded`);
        client.commands.set(fileName, fileContents);
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${fileName}.js`)];
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to read [this](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#command-aliases)? Maybe it helps.

Comment: I still have no idea how to do it...